# Can I encode an NFC tag to send HTTP POST data?

Tags: nfc

Can I encode an NFC tag to send HTTP POST data? Or can I only use HTTP GET?

I have Googled extensively, but can't seem to find an answer (which, I suppose, implies that it is HTTP GET only, but I would like someone to say so).

---

[Update - 6 years later]  This project was abandoned, but it was basically advertising, embedding NFC tokens in posters.

As such, it should work on any Android, out of the box, with no helper apps being necessary (my bad; maybe I ought to have made that clearer).

The extra step to install an app would drastically lower the number of people who scanned the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can only encode a URL on the tag. The tag neither contains an instruction to issue a HTTP GET request nor a HTTP POST request.

How the URL is interpreted and processed depends on the app that opens the URL. Typically that app will be a web browser and that web browser will typically treat the URL as if it was typed into the address bar. Consequently, the web browsers usually opens the URL by issuing a GET request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, NFC Tools PRO has a Post option https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakdev.nfctools.pro&hl=en

Comment: As the OP, I wish that the downvoter had given an explanation. It would have helped me :-(

Comment: I know that it has been 6 years, but could your link doesn't mention Post. Do I have to D/L the app & try it? If you have a link to something online that says that it can encode POST requests, then I will award you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Tasker application can be set to send any http request to any address when it gets in contact with a NFC tag that it recognizes.

Comment: Not really an answer, as it would require all users of my tags to install Tasker (and maybe pay for it?). This project was abandoned, but it was basically advertising, embedding NFC tokens in posters. The extra step to install Tasker would have drastically lowered the number of people who scanned the tag. I will update the question to make this clear.